# How to use paste command in the shell file

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix, paste

I have two variables and I want to paste them beside each other in two columns. The problem is the command is working in the terminal of Unix but not within a shell script when I'm submitting it as a job. Below is the script:

```
value_1="name1"
value_2="name2"

value_3=$(paste <(echo "$value_1") <(echo "$value_2") -d '\t')
echo "$value_3" >> test.txt
```

it is giving two errors:

```
- syntax error near unexpected token `('
- `paste <(echo "$value_1") <(echo "$value_2") -d '\t')'
```

Does somebody have any idea what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you using a shell that supports `<(command)` syntax? Not all do.

Comment: doesn;t `value_3="$value_1$value_2"` work? The error message you're getting looks like you are using `#!/bin/sh`. You'll need to use a newer shell, usually `#!/bin/bash`. Good luck.

Comment: and what do you expect `-d '\t'` to do? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, Thanks, it works with #!/bin/bash!! How did you know that?! -d '\t' is for separating with TAB.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` how? Just years of reading Qs here ;-) . If you need a tab between $v1 a and $v2, then just put it there, `v3="${v1}<tabChar>${v2}"` `paste` is overkill for your example text AND I'm surprised that `paste` can "see" that option inside of a `<(process_sub)`. Even if it works, better to follow conventions and use `paste -d '\t' ...` ...... OR are you really trying to "join" multi-line values? If so, I don't think you can get the results you want using variables in that fashion. Save things into temp files and then put into a variable OR preferably, just use the temp file. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

the script is working actually.

[image: scrot]

Use shebang in your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
value_1="name1"
value_2="name2"

value_3=$(paste <(echo "$value_1") <(echo "$value_2") -d '\t')
echo "$value_3" >> test.txt
```